# Visual studio 2010, I do not see Merge Changes in Merge Tool Option. How can I enable it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and I do not see Merge Changes in Merge Tool Option. How can I enable it?

[image: no Merge Changes in Merge Tool Option]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the message: *A writable file by the same name exists locally*. This is a quirk of TFVC with server workspaces, or at least it was 8 years ago.

It's just saying "someone made this file writable, but it's not checked out on the server, so we have no way of knowing which version is correct. Do you want to use whatever is on the server, or whatever is on the client?". This will happen if you modify files outside of Visual Studio while using server workspaces.

In this case, you probably just want to click "keep local file contents".